# KQL Regex Extraction for a string

Tags: kql

I am trying to pull description value from below parameter.

"Condition":null,"ConditionVersion":null,"Description":"**ASR 2729**"}}","eventCategory":"Administrative"

I only need to extract the Value = **ASR 2729**

I tried extract using different condition. Could not crack the correct regex.

Comment: This input doesn't seem to make much sense, e.g., where did `"}}"` came from? Why do you have backslashes in your text (it can be seen when you edit the post)? Please fix your sample data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if the input is a string and isn't a valid JSON payload, you can use the `parse` operator.

see:

- [`parse` operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator)

for example:

```
print input = '"Condition":null,"ConditionVersion":null,"Description":"ASR 2729"}}","eventCategory":"Administrative"'
| parse input with * '"Description":"' description '"' *
```

| input | description |
| --- | --- |
| "Condition":null,"ConditionVersion":null,"Description":"ASR 2729"}}","eventCategory":"Administrative" | ASR 2729 |

if the input is dynamic, or is a string that is a valid JSON payload, you can use dynamic object accessors.

see:

- [the `dynamic` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic)
- [the `parse_json()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction)

for example:

```
print input = '{"Condition":null,"ConditionVersion":null,"Description":"ASR 2729","eventCategory":"Administrative"}'
| extend input = parse_json(input)
| extend description = tostring(input.Description)
```

| input | description |
| --- | --- |
| { "Condition": null, "ConditionVersion": null, "Description": "ASR 2729", "eventCategory": "Administrative" } | ASR 2729 |

```
print input = dynamic({"Condition":null,"ConditionVersion":null,"Description":"ASR 2729","eventCategory":"Administrative"})
| extend description = tostring(input.Description)
```

| input | description |
| --- | --- |
| { "Condition": null, "ConditionVersion": null, "Description": "ASR 2729", "eventCategory": "Administrative" } | ASR 2729 |